# Simple import of module from one .ts file to another

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor, commonjs

I am having problem importing classes from one .ts file to another .ts file.

***This is my project structure:***

[image]

I am trying to import print.ts to testing.ts.

***This is what my tsconfig.json looks like:***

[image]

***Contents of my testing.ts:***

```
import { names } from 'testing';
console.log(names.printFirstName());
```

***Contents of my print.ts:***

```
class nameCollection {
static printFirstName(){
    return 'OYEAAAH';
    };
}

export {nameCollection as names};
```

***I am running my tests using:*** 
    `node testing.js`

And I am getting:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: the names module you are trying to import comes from print.ts `import {names} from './print';` il print.ts is in the same directory

Comment: Yes it is. I tried using the `./src/nested/print` and it worked. I just wanted to declare it in in tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript does path mapping for module resolution, you are mixing directories and files

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "testing/*": ["src/nested/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then in your scripts you can import `import {names} from 'testing/print';`

check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html for more details